# Allow more than one location or wildcard in jobs match filter

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I was trying the "match settings" of jobs.

Lets say I'm ready to work anywhere, be it United states, Europe, Asia... as long as I'm working on the technologies I like and the compensation is good.

I tried setting more than one location, but it seems if I choose United states for example, then I can further only add city inside united states.

So I decided to leave that blank, and use the other cool features like "technology", "Developer type" etc.

But when I try to save those, I get this:

> [image]

and the other settings can't be saved.

Why? Can't I be willing to work anywhere as long as other conditions meet..?

Please provide an options to choose more than one location, something like:

```
 Virgin Islands,United States;Australia;Singapore
```

or leave it blank (consider as wild card) and see all jobs matching rest of the criteria

Answer (score 9):

We're planning to add multiple location support to the matching algorithm in the very near future. It'll probably be [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/267572) :)

**UPDATE**

Support for multiple locations was added to the matching preferences and algorithm a few weeks back. It optionally uses the home location set in your CV / developer story and supplements it with additional locations that you enter.

Comment: So, how to use that functionalty? By separating the options by semicolons like: `Australia;Singapore`?

Comment: @vahdet not sure I understand the question; you can add multiple locations in your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current), not in a search

Comment: Sorry, I was just asked for the search location field at the top in the Jobs page. Apparently the comment does not belong to this thread.