# Stack Overflow Jobs "Willing to relocate" allows only one answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

Similar to question: *[Allow more than one location or wildcard in jobs match filter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313124/allow-more-than-one-location-or-wildcard-in-jobs-match-filter)*.

I am adding my profile to Stack Exchange Jobs, and I clicked on the "Willing to Relocate?" option and wanted to enter some states or areas where I am willing to go.

I tried several ways, but it seems I can only add one city or state to the locations to where I am willing to relocate! Each time I tried "ALL" or "Anywhere" or "Southern US" it would select some state with one of the characters I entered.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should be available under the "Edit CV" tab, in the "Job Status" section:

[image: Willing to relocate]

After ticking that box, you can use the "Add Location" link to add more locations:

[image: Add Locations]

Most things that you would consider a "location" are accepted, such as cities, states, countries, and even continents:

[image: Moar locations]

If this is not working for you, then you may have encountered a bug, and we definitely will want to get it fixed!

Comment: Great Answer, Thanks @ross

Comment: I am not sure how to mark it as answered unless it has already been done somehow since it says "answered yesterday".

Comment: @LPETEET That means he posted this answer yesterday. To accept the answer, click the check mark under the voting arrows. It will turn green.

Comment: You can also check the up arrow to upvote the answer if you found it useful...

Comment: How can I set `allow relocation` now. I have checked this post, but its 3 yrs old now, and since then, there has been a lot of change in the GUI of the website, should I raise another question for this?

Comment: I no longer work for Stack Overflow, but you can find these settings under your user profile, under the section "Job  preferences"