# How do I specify that I'm willing to relocate anywhere?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

How can I specify that I'm open to any relocation offers without writing down all countries in the world? When I put in 'anywhere', the add button is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Beyond this, there is a badge at the top of the "traditional view" that says **"Currently not open to relocating from your current location."**--but I cannot find anywhere to enable or disable this choice.  There's the check box that says "Willing to work remotely" but I don't see anywhere that lets you say you're willing to relocate.  Can someone share a screenshot of the picture that says whether you are willing to relocate or not?  Because I don't see it.

Comment: @HostileFork I assume, since it's the traditional view. there's no longer an option to change it. Checking "Willing to work remotely" changes nothing in that matter.

Comment: @Filnor So it's an old setting that no longer can be changed?  (e.g. [this no longer is what the setting looks like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314286/211160))  That would be a bug.  Next question would be...how do you report a bug?

Comment: @HostileFork Honestly I'm not sure if there was a setting for it. The right way to report a bug not related to the security of the page/networks is a post here on meta, of course.

Comment: Very useful option, but it doesn't exist. I also remember that Linkedin didn't support it, so it will not be a surprise if it remains not-an-option in the future as well.

Comment: The key issue is that while you may be *willing* to relocate anywhere, you're not actually legally *able* to.

Comment: @OrangeDog but this has nothing to do with what you're legally able to do. Besides, this is a catch-22: to get a work visa, you often need an employer, and to get an employer, you need him to see you in search results.

Comment: Has this bug been fixed yet?  I can't put a stackoverflow link on my resume until I can get rid of the "Currently not open to relocating from your current location." note.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option at a moment.

Stack Overflow remembers that you will like/dislike some countries and also some countries will accept/reject your visa application -- it is not always possible to get living/working permit for some countries like Korea, Israel, Switzerland, etc.

It will save the time of employer if job seekers will mark countries list where they can get or already have the work permit.
You can check "Willing to work remotely" and that will mean that you would be available for the whole world but without the relocation.

The employee needs to be at least able to get a visa theoretically.

> 'Willing to relocate' = I want + I can

Comment: But "willing to relocate" is not the same as "have a work visa", so I don't understand how is this relevant.

Comment: The employee needs to be at least able to get a visa theoretically. 'Willing to relocate' = I want + I can.

Comment: What is the bound on "theoretically", and why should I be responsible for it? I don't know how the law works in all the countries in the world, and figuring out visa sponsorship is traditionally more of a responsibility of employer than employee.